# Jetbrains Pycharm SQL vs Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I'm running a complicated SQL script in Oracle SQL Developer. The query starts with

```
DEFINE custom_date = "'22-JUL-2016'"
```

While this works fine in Oracle SQL Developer I get an error in jetbrains:
`<statement> expected got DEFINE`

Also when I run the query it says:

```
ORA-00919: invalid function
```

even though it all works fine in Orace SQl Developer.

Is there anything specific I need to configure in Jetbrains Pycharm to be able to execute Oracle SQL queries correctly?

Answer (score 0):

DEFINE isn't a core feature of the database, instead it's a command in SQL*Plus.

SQL Developer has as script engine which supports all of the SQL*Plus commands, including DEFINE, which is why it works when you run it there.

DEFINE just creates a variable and assigns a text value to it. You'll need to re-write your code to declare the variable and assign values to it instead.

[Docs for DEFINE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#i1211029)

Comment: I switched it to SQL plus, but it still gives an error: invalid function in this `SELECT -- parallel(12)
        DISTINCT
        FIRST_VALUE (RS_DSET_COB_DT) OVER(PARTITION BY &PARTITIONING. ORDER BY PERFECT_MATCH,VERSION_MISMATCH,ONE_SIDED,TRD_VER DESC NULLS LAST RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)RS_DSET_COB_DT,` Any suggestions why?